# Functorial choice of pullbacks in a locally cartesian closed $(\infty,1)$-category

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

In a locally cartesian closed category $\mathcal C$, for every map $f:A\to B$, there is an associated pullback functor $f^* : \mathcal C/B \to\mathcal C/A$. Moreover, if $g:B\to C$, the two functors $(g\circ f)^*$ and $f^*\circ g^*$ are *canonically isomorphic*, but they have no reason to be "equal". Even in the category of sets, the usual choice of pullbacks is only functorial up to isomorphism (see [this paper of Hofmann](http://www.springerlink.com/content/5077x3h92151072u/fulltext.pdf))

This gives a pseudo functor from $\mathcal C^\mathrm{op}$ to $\mathcal{Cat}$. The fact that this is only a pseudo functor and not a functor causes some problems when trying to interpret dependent type theory in locally cartesian closed categories (see for example the previous paper of Hofmann, or [this paper of Curien](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/DIA/DIA_1990__23_/DIA_1990__23__43_0/DIA_1990__23__43_0.pdf)).

I was wondering what happens when you pass to $(\infty,1)$-categories. Intuitively, the fact that pullback are only functorial up to isomorphism should not be a problem anymore, because $(\infty,1)$-functors are also only functorial up to isomorphism anyway.

So my question is, **if $\mathcal C$ is a [locally cartesian closed $(\infty,1)$-category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+cartesian+closed+%28infinity,1%29-category), does there always exists a functorial choice of pullbacks?** (by which I mean an $(\infty,1)$-functor from $\mathcal C^\mathrm{op}$ to $(\infty,1)\mathcal{Cat}$ sending objects to slice categories and morphisms to pullback functors)

Comment: Is that functorial in the usual $(\infty,1)$-sense?

Comment: Up until the final parenthetical, I thought this question was asking for a *strictly* functorial choice of pullbacks, not an "(infinity,1)-functorial" choice.  The example cited of the 1-categorical case is about strict functoriality, with pseudo (2-)functoriality being automatic.  Strict functoriality is also what's necessary for modeling type theory.  I think (infinity,1)-functoriality of pullbacks is analogous to pseudofunctoriality, not to strict functoriality, and isn't good enough for modeling type theory.


Comment: @Mike If we want to model (homotopy) type theory in weak $(\infty,1)$-categories, we will have to deal with weak functors somehow. I agree that the usual models of type theory use strict functoriality, but perhaps that there will be someday a notion of model in a weak $(\infty,1)$-category where strict does not mean anything.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is probably to appeal to the equivalence between functors $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}} \to \text{Cat}_{\infty}$ and Cartesian fibrations over $\mathcal{C}$. Roughly speaking, a Cartesian fibration $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{C}$ corresponds to a functor that sends $c \in \mathcal{C}$ to the fibre $\mathcal{E}_{c}$ of the fibration at $c$ and a morphism $f \colon c \to d$ in $\mathcal{C}$ to a functor $f^* \colon \mathcal{E}_{d} \to \mathcal{E}_{c}$ that takes an object $x$ in $\mathcal{E}_{d}$ to the source of a Cartesian arrow over $f$ with target $x$. This functor is unique up to a contractible space of choices.

The "evaluation at 1" functor $\text{Fun}(\Delta^1, \mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$ is a Cartesian fibration precisely when $\mathcal{C}$ has pullbacks - a "Cartesian arrow" in $\text{Fun}(\Delta^1, \mathcal{C})$ is the same things as a pullback diagram - so the corresponding functor sends $c \in \mathcal{C}$ to the fibre $\mathcal{C}_{/c}$ of this map and a morphism $f$ in $\mathcal{C}$ to "pullback by $f$".

Comment: This is much nicer! Good to learn about that neat correspondence!

Comment: Thanks! Does this also proves that when the $(\infty,1)$-category is locally cartesian closed, there is an $(\infty,1)$-functorial choice of right adjoints to the pullback functor?

Comment: A map $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{C}$ that's both a Cartesian and a coCartesian fibration corresponds to $F \colon \mathcal{C} \to \text{Cat}_{\infty}$ and $G \colon \mathcal{C}^{\text{op}} \to \text{Cat}_{\infty}$ such that $F(f)$ is left adjoint to $G(f)$ for all $f$ in $\mathcal{C}$. For right adjoints to pullbacks we can consider the opposite of the evaluation functor, $\text{Fun}(\Delta^1, \mathcal{C})^{\text{op}} \to \mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$. This is coCartesian if $\mathcal{C}$ has finite limits, and Cartesian iff each pullback functor has a right adjoint (Higher Topos Theory 5.2.2.5).

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I think the answer is that, yes, you can define such a functor. The main reasons are as follows:

1. Pullbacks themselves are only defined up to coherent homotopy equivalence.
2. Compositions in an infinity category (like $Cat_\infty$) are only defined up to coherent equivalence.
3. Any two good choices of a "pullback functor" $f^*: \mathcal{C}/A \rightarrow \mathcal{C}/B$ must be equivalent.

I'm sure there's some highly general proposition in HTT where Lurie proves something where this result is a special case, but I couldn't seem to find such a thing so I've written down some words that I think constitute a (rather messy) proof... I think a lot of what I say is probably unnecessary, so I'll try to clean it up a bit later:

[write up](http://washington.academia.edu/DylanWilson/Teaching/29740/Functoriality_of_pullbacks_in_infty-categories)

(also- it'd be really nice if I could actually just post documents here since I don't really have a webpage, I just sort of made one up on some site that I'm not even sure everyone can see...? Is there a way to do this?)

Comment: Also: the document probably needs proofreading, and I'm certain there were various places where I needed to put an "op" and didn't... Maybe I should have just done it for pushouts instead. 

Comment: Also! Why did you need locally Cartesian closed? It seems like existence of finite limits is all you need...

Comment: Dylan, one word: nLab.

Comment: Indeed, I only needed the existence of finite limits for this question. In semantics of type theory, local cartesian closedness is used for interpreting dependent products.